# Passing a vector or dataframe column string date convert to Date format

Tags: julia

I have loaded data into a .csv within Julia.

I wish to convert my string Date to Date format:

```
julia> head(df)
6×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Date       │ Open    │ High    │ Low     │ Close   │ Adj_Close │ Volume  │
├─────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1993-01-29 │ 43.9687 │ 43.9687 │ 43.75   │ 43.9375 │ 27.6073   │ 1003200 │
│ 2   │ 1993-02-01 │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 27.8036   │ 480500  │
│ 3   │ 1993-02-02 │ 44.2187 │ 44.375  │ 44.125  │ 44.3437 │ 27.8625   │ 201300  │
│ 4   │ 1993-02-03 │ 44.4062 │ 44.8437 │ 44.375  │ 44.8125 │ 28.1571   │ 529400  │
│ 5   │ 1993-02-04 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0937 │ 44.4687 │ 45.0    │ 28.2749   │ 531500  │
│ 6   │ 1993-02-05 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0625 │ 44.7187 │ 44.9687 │ 28.2552   │ 492100  │
```

The type is:

```
julia> showcols(df)
6258×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name      │ Eltype                           │ Missing │ Values                    │
├───────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 1     │ Date      │ Union{Missings.Missing, String}  │ 0       │ 1993-01-29  …  2017-12-01 │
│ 2     │ Open      │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  264.76        │
│ 3     │ High      │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  265.31        │
│ 4     │ Low       │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.75  …  260.76          │
│ 5     │ Close     │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9375  …  264.46        │
│ 6     │ Adj_Close │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 27.6073  …  264.46        │
│ 7     │ Volume    │ Union{Int64, Missings.Missing}   │ 0       │ 1003200  …  159947700     │
```

Right now the Date is a string.

So wish to convert the column a Date format.

trying:

```
df[:Date, DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")]
```

and

```
df[df[:Date] = DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")]
```

with error:

MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type DateFormat{Symbol("yyyy-mm-dd"),Tuple{Base.Dates.DatePart{'y'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'m'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'d'}}} to an object of type String
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor String(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
in setindex! at DataFrames\src\dataframe\dataframe.jl:376
in fill! at base\multidimensional.jl:841
REPL

encase my syntax is wrong I make a vector x from the date column:

```
x = df[:Date]

Date(x, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Union{Missings.Missing, String},1} to an object of type Int64
REPL

This is easy with R but Julia can not find that great of information, any assistance appreciated.

I am also following this link:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/dates/

Here is an example:

```
julia> df = Dates.DateFormat("y-m-d");

julia> dt = Date("2015-01-01",df)
2015-01-01

julia> dt2 = Date("2015-01-02",df)
2015-01-02
```

Why cant I pass a vector or data frame column through this??

**Update:**

This works when I pass one element from the vector:

```
julia> Date(x[1], Dates.DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"))
1993-01-29
```

I just want to convert every element to this format and store in the data frame

Comment: Based on the link you posted, be aware that you appear to be reading the docs from julia v0.4. A *lot* has changed since v0.4, eg the broadcasting operator `.` in the (very nice) answer provided. Best to read the docs labeled *stable* and use v0.6 if you've just come across to julia. (although v0.7 should be ready fairly soon, and involves *many* changes from v0.6 - but it will also be compatible with v1.0 and so should be the last big set of breaking changes that users have to deal with for many years).

Comment: Ok great - thanks for pointing this out. Many google searches leading to v.04. Cheers, Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write `Date.(x, Dates.DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"))` to get what you want.

Notice the `.` after `Date` - it tells Julia to apply `Date` function to all elements of `x` and `Dates.DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")` will be reused in every call as it is a scalar.

The details are explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Broadcast-and-vectorization-1.

As a side note if you use latest version of *CSV.jl* package then it should detect `Date` type automatically:

```
julia> data="""Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj_Close,Volume
       1993-01-29,43.9687,43.9687,43.75,43.9375,27.6073,1003200
       1993-02-01,43.9687,44.25,43.9687,44.25,27.8036,480500
       1993-02-02,44.2187,44.375,44.125 ,44.3437,27.8625,201300"""
"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj_Close,Volume\n1993-01-29,43.9687,43.9687,43.75,43.9375,27.6073,1003200\n1993-02-01,43.9687,44.25,43.9687,44.25,27.8036,480500\n1993-02-02,44.2187,44.375,44.125 ,44.3437,27.8625,201300"

julia> showcols(CSV.read(IOBuffer(data)))
3×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name      │ Eltype                           │ Missing │ Values                    │
├───────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 1     │ Date      │ Union{Date, Missings.Missing}    │ 0       │ 1993-01-29  …  1993-02-02 │
│ 2     │ Open      │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  44.2187       │
│ 3     │ High      │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  44.375        │
│ 4     │ Low       │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.75  …  44.125          │
│ 5     │ Close     │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 43.9375  …  44.3437       │
│ 6     │ Adj_Close │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 0       │ 27.6073  …  27.8625       │
│ 7     │ Volume    │ Union{Int64, Missings.Missing}   │ 0       │ 1003200  …  201300        │
```

And even if it would not you can pass `types` argument (in example below it avoids an union with `Missing` if you would not want this for some reason):

```
julia> showcols(CSV.read(IOBuffer(data), types=[String; fill(Float64, 5); Int]))
3×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name      │ Eltype  │ Missing │ Values                    │
├───────┼───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 1     │ Date      │ String  │ 0       │ 1993-01-29  …  1993-02-02 │
│ 2     │ Open      │ Float64 │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  44.2187       │
│ 3     │ High      │ Float64 │ 0       │ 43.9687  …  44.375        │
│ 4     │ Low       │ Float64 │ 0       │ 43.75  …  44.125          │
│ 5     │ Close     │ Float64 │ 0       │ 43.9375  …  44.3437       │
│ 6     │ Adj_Close │ Float64 │ 0       │ 27.6073  …  27.8625       │
│ 7     │ Volume    │ Int64   │ 0       │ 1003200  …  201300        │
```

EDIT: Under DataFrames.jl version 0.14 or later use `describe` instead of `showcols`.

Comment: Ok very good! Can you show me a syntax to convert it directly within the dataframe?

Comment: df[:Date] = Date.(df[:Date])

Comment: Thanks for your help today. My first foray from R to Julia :)

Comment: I tried this and got `MethodError: no method matching iterate(::DataFrame)`

Comment: What did you exactly try? The question was about `DateFromat` not `DataFrames. Also note that `showcols` is now deprecated in DataFrames.jl and you should use `describe` function. I have added the information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
# Pull date column and store in vector
    x = df[:Date]

    # loop to iterate through each element in vector, converting to Date format 
    v = []
    for i in 1:length(x)
        z = Date(x[i], Dates.DateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"))
        push!(v,z)
    end

    # Check format 
    julia> v[1] - v[3]
    -4 days

    # cbind() R equivalent hcat() to existing data frame
    df = hcat(df,v)

With the output:


    julia> head(df)
    6×8 DataFrames.DataFrame
    │ Row │ Date       │ Open    │ High    │ Low     │ Close   │ Adj_Close │ Volume  │ x1         │
    ├─────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────┼────────────┤
    │ 1   │ 1993-01-29 │ 43.9687 │ 43.9687 │ 43.75   │ 43.9375 │ 27.6073   │ 1003200 │ 1993-01-29 │
    │ 2   │ 1993-02-01 │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 27.8036   │ 480500  │ 1993-02-01 │
    │ 3   │ 1993-02-02 │ 44.2187 │ 44.375  │ 44.125  │ 44.3437 │ 27.8625   │ 201300  │ 1993-02-02 │
    │ 4   │ 1993-02-03 │ 44.4062 │ 44.8437 │ 44.375  │ 44.8125 │ 28.1571   │ 529400  │ 1993-02-03 │
    │ 5   │ 1993-02-04 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0937 │ 44.4687 │ 45.0    │ 28.2749   │ 531500  │ 1993-02-04 │
    │ 6   │ 1993-02-05 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0625 │ 44.7187 │ 44.9687 │ 28.2552   │ 492100  │ 1993-02-05 │
```

Comment: Instead of using `hcat` probably simpler would be `df[:newdate] = v`. Also vector `v` has type `Vector{Any}` and you probably want a type `Vector{Date}` in which case you should write `v=Date[]`.

Comment: Your great! Thank you! So I pre specify the type here